# Apply the same event handler to multiple forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I am trying to loop the jQuery code below. Each form has a unique `id` starting from `#product_1` to `#product_35`. I don't want to copy+paste the code below:

```
$('#product_1').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var jqxhr = $.ajax({
    url: "https://script.google.com/macros/s/SAMPLE/exec",
    method: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    data: $('#product_1').serialize()
  }).success();
})};
```

I came up with the code below and I'm kinda stuck to loop the code.

```
var i;
for (i = 1; i < 36; i++) {    
  $('#product_' + 'i').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var jqxhr = $.ajax({
      url: "https://script.google.com/macros/s/SAMPLE/exec",
      method: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      data: $('#product_' + 'i').serialize()
    }).success();
  })
};
```

Could anyone help me to fix this?  Many thanks in advance

Comment: Don't use incremental `id` attributes. It's an anti-pattern. Put a common class on all the forms and then use `each()`, for example `$('.yourForm').each(function() { /* do something */ });` then use `data: $(this).serialize()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: Along with the above comments you don't need add quotes to the incrememnt var `i` for future reference

Comment: `$('#product_' + i)` - remove the quotes from around `'i'` and you should be ok.  But do consider changing the approach as detailed above.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using the `object $('form')`?

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  //Get the dinamic #id from the form.
  var idForm = $(this).attr('id');

  var jqxhr = $.ajax({

    url: "https://script.google.com/macros/s/SAMPLE/exec",
    method: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    data: $('#'+idForm).serialize() // Or $(this).serialize(),
    success: function(data){
          //data = response from the url
    }

  })

  );
})};
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do by following two ways,

1. Use JQuery start with attribute selector

```js
$('form[id^=product_]').on('submit', function(e) {
    var $form = $(this);
    e.preventDefault();

    var jqxhr = $.ajax({

    url: "https://script.google.com/macros/s/SAMPLE/exec",
    method: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    data: $form.serialize()

    }).success(

    );
    })};
```

2. Use common class for all forms, where provide class = "submitForm" for all form element (you can use any name for class)

```js
$('form.submitForm').on('submit', function(e) {
var $form = $(this);
e.preventDefault();

var jqxhr = $.ajax({

url: "https://script.google.com/macros/s/SAMPLE/exec",
method: "GET",
dataType: "json",
data: $form.serialize()

}).success(

);
})};
```

Comment: Just FYI, backticks don't work in markdown when following bullet points. You have to use the language tags

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, thanks for the information and editing the post!!

Answer (score -1):

Don't use incremental `id` attributes. It's an anti-pattern. Put a common class on all the forms and then select them all in a single jQuery object. Then you can bind a single event handler to all of them.

Within that event handler you can use the `this` keyword to refer to the specific form which raised the event in order to serialise it.

Also note that there is no `success` method on the jqXHR object returned from a `$.ajax()` call. I presume you intended to use `done()` or `then()` instead. Try this:

```
$('.product-form').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var jqxhr = $.ajax({
    url: "https://script.google.com/macros/s/SAMPLE/exec",
    method: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    data: $(this).serialize()
  }).done(function() {
    // request sent successfully
  });
})
```